# Search for a word and replace everything behind it

Tags: javascript

I hava a url like

```
mysite.net/home/index/page/XX
```

while XX is any number. I need to replace XX and remove everything that might be behind XX. So I would like to remove everything behind `page/` by replacing it with a number.

There are a lot of methods for string manipulation http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_string.asp

I know how to perform this but I am not sure which methods to use. So I ended with getting the `lastIndexOf("page/")`. So this +1 would give me the starting point for replacing the string. The entire length of the string would be the ending point.

Any ideas?

Comment: you want to remove everything up to XX and then replace xx with another number?

Comment: yea just replace everything behind page/

Comment: The word you're looking for is 'after' rather than 'behind'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will do the trick, by using regular expression:

```
"mysite.net/home/index/page/XX".replace(/\/page\/.*/, '/page/123')
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't get your problem because you may have found everything you need...

```
var yourURI = "mysite.net/home/index/page/XX";
var theDelimiter = "page/";
var yourNewIndex = "42";
var yourNewURI = null;

var lastIndexOfDelimiter = yourURI.lastIndexOf(theDelimiter);
if (lastIndexOfDelimiter != -1)
{
  yourNewURI = yourURI.substr(0, lastIndexOfDelimiter + theDelimiter.length) + yourNewIndex;
}
```

Is that what you want?

Answer (score 1):

```
var url = "mysite.net/home/index/page/XX"
return url.substr(-(url.length - (url.lastIndexOf("page/") + 5))))
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a direct answer to your question, but the way I solve this kind of problem is to have the **server** calculate a 'base url' (mysite.net/home/index/page/ in your case), and write it to a js variable at the time the page is built.

For two different ASP.NET MVC versions (there would be something similar you could do in any other framework) this looks like this:

```
var baseUrl = '@ViewBag.BaseUrl';
```

or

```
var baseUrl = '<%: ViewData["BaseUrl"] %>';
```

This has the big advantage that the page JS doesn't start to know about URL formation, so if you change your URL routing you don't find little breakages all over the place.

At least for ASP.NET MVC, you can use the frameworks routing API to generate the base URL at the server side.